# Type Assertion in TypeScript without assigning a new variable

Tags: typescript

I have a function that returns values with one of two interfaces, like so:

```
interface K {
    A:number;
    NUM:number;
}

interface L {
    A:string;
    STR:string;
}

function FUN():K|L { }

var x:K|L = FUN();
```

but I can't access the non-shared property using a type-guard like this one:

```
if(typeof x.A === 'string'){
    console.log(x.STR) // Property 'STR' does not exist on type 'K | L'
}
```

even though the if clause does distinguish between the two types.   I know I can use `as` operator with a variable assignment to indicate the type to the compiler like so:

```
if(typeof x.A === 'string'){
    var y = x as L;
    console.log(y.STR) // OK 
}
```

but that seems a bit kludgy as this add a unnecessary `var` statement and assignment in the resulting js code:

```
function FUN() { }
var x = FUN();
if (typeof x.A === 'string') {
    var y = x; // unnecessary...
    console.log(y.STR); 
}
```

Is there any way to indicate the type in this situation without the extra `var y=x;` in the JS code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, TypeScript supports type casting. You should be able to do:

```
if(typeof x.A === 'string'){
    console.log((<L>x).STR);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.  That doesn't seem to work.   Casting would work if I had a variable that was already declared as type `L`, as in: `var x:L; x = <L>FUN();
`.  But doesn't re-cast x once it's already defined (`var`'d).

Comment: Oops, you're right. I needed some parenthesis. I edited my answer. Give that a try.

Comment: Thanks so much! Solved my problem and I learned an new usage for the type assertion!

Comment: No problem. Glad I was able to help you out.